# How to use CDN to accelerate simple video site with PHP dynamic loading video files like Moodle?

Tags: php, cdn, streaming, video, moodle

I created a site with Moodle, and not very satisfied with the connection speed for video files stored on server. And I know CDN can accelerate the video file loading speed.

But I 'm quite new and not familiar with CDN. I simply wish anyone accessing the videos must log in to my source site. But I heard CDN can only accelerate static files.

The url to the video file would be `https://example.com/my.php/110/mod_page/content/2/543.mp4`

And it cannot be accessed if not logged in.

So can CDN fetch the mp4 file? Will simply accelerate the domain names work?

Comment: "How To" questions are generally not on-topic. How to use a CDN with protected content is probably specific to that CDN, but it can be done: https://blog.cloudflare.com/token-authentication-for-cached-private-content-and-apis/

Answer (score -1):

Since this question is long gone, I actually tried a CDN service on this.

The CDN works as it can accelerate once someone request the mp4 file at the first time, it gets loaded to CDN remote server, then the next requests are going to fast CDN servers instead of the original source server.

They provide many kinds of authentication services too, for one of them is the referrer method, that is the mp4 file request can only come from specific domain names, in case someone else link them other places.

Other methods include time stamp authentication, remote video player, ts stream split etc.

So CDN works with moodle indeed.